# find products that have no sales against them which are nine months old or older

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to find all product codes that have no sales against them for the last 9 months so I can delete them.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT PI.ID as 'Product ID', ItemDescription, SOD.ID as 'Sales ID', so.despatchdate
    FROM ProductItem as PI LEFT OUTER JOIN saleorderdetail as SOD
    ON PI.ID = SOD.productitemid
inner join saleorder as SO
on SO.id = sod.saleorderid
    where SO.despatchdate <= (getdate() - 273);
```

The result is not correct.

Comment: Use DateDiff() with `month` as the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Use `not exists`:

```
select * from ProductItem pi
where not exists(select * from saleorderdetail sod
                 inner join saleorder so so.id = sod.saleorderid
                 where pi.ID = sod.productitemid and so.despatchdate >= (getdate() - 273))
```

The following will be more correct:

```
select * from ProductItem pi
where not exists(select * from saleorderdetail sod
                 inner join saleorder so so.id = sod.saleorderid
                 where pi.ID = sod.productitemid and dateadd(m, -9, getdate()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @products table
(
    Id int primary key not null
    , Name nvarchar(32) not null
)

insert @products values( 1, 'Has Recent Sales Order' )
insert @products values( 2, 'Does Not Have Recent Sales Order' )

declare @sos table
(
    Id int primary key not null,
    DespatchDate datetime not null
)

insert @sos values ( 1, getdate() )
insert @sos values ( 2, DATEADD( month, -10, getdate() ) )

declare @sods table
(
    ProductId int not null,
    SaleOrderId int not null
)

insert @sods values( 1, 1 )
insert @sods values( 2, 2 )


-- select only those products that do not have a recent sales order
SELECT 
    PI.ID as 'Product ID'
    , PI.Name -- for demonstrative purposes only
FROM 
    @products as PI 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @sods as SOD
        ON PI.ID = SOD.ProductId
    left outer join @sos as SO
        on SO.id = sod.saleorderid
            -- retreive sales orders within past 9 months only
            and DATEADD( month, -9, getdate() ) <= SO.despatchdate
group by
    PI.ID
    , PI.Name -- for demonstrative purposes only
having
    -- only sales orders in past 9 months were returned
    -- so filter for no sales orders
    count(so.id) = 0
```